# How can I estimate the size of my gzipped script?

Tags: javascript, gzip, minify

How can I estimate the size of my JavaScript file after it is gzipped? Are there online tools for this? Or is it similar to using winzip for example?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home lets you paste in code, and it will give you compression ratios for a particular file before and after GZIP.

> ```
> Original Size:    90 bytes (100 bytes gzipped)
> Compiled Size:    55 bytes (68 bytes gzipped)
> Saved 38.89% off the original size (32.00% off the gzipped size)
> ```

You can use the pretty-print and white-space only options to estimate the compression of non-minified content.

If you need an estimate:

- Start with 100 JS files that have gone through the same minification pipeline.
- For each file, compute the ratio in sizes between `gzip -c "$f" | wc -c` and `wc -c "$f"`
- The average of those ratios is an approximation of the compression you should expect for a similar JS file.

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) contains command line implementations of `gzip` and `wc` for Windows.

Comment: thx! I'll try Cygwin, but for now the closure compiler gave me the answer I needed.

Answer (score 136):

If you're on unix - `gzip -c filename.min.js | wc -c` will give you a byte count of the gzipped file

Comment: @Christophe : gzip is available on Windows through Cygwin or UnxUtils.

Comment: Thanks, this is also useful to know raw unzipped byte size by doing `gunzip -c myfile | wc -c` or `zcat myfile | wc -c`

Comment: To get the un-gzipped size of an un-gzipped file: `cat filename.js | wc -c`.

Answer (score 16):

Directly from the terminal,

```
gzip -9 -c path/to/file.js | wc -c | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=10
```

If you need the original size for comprison,

```
cat path/to/file.js | wc -c | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=10
```

To get it programatically there are utilities like [gzip-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-size). It's a node package but you can install it globally as a general tool.

Answer (score 9):

### [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) supports compressing to the GZIP format.

I often use this to approximate and compare file sizes.

When creating an archive, look for `Archive Format`, and `gzip` is the 3rd option.

### Update:

In the comments, we discussed that there might be a difference between 7-zip's GZIP compression, versus an actual server's GZIP compression.  So, I compared using just the homepage of http://www.google.com/.
Google's GZIP'd payload was 36,678 bytes.  7-zip, with "gzip Normal" setting, was 35,559 (3% smaller).  With "gzip Fastest" setting, it was 37,673 (3% larger).

So, long story short: **7-zip had results that were about 97% accurate**.

Comment: Sorry, [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) can make **smaller* archives than most CLI GZIP packers.  Great if you want the smallest, bad if you want a precise byte count for what most web servers will make on the fly (which I assume is the intended scenario?

Comment: @tomByrer Thanks for the info ... can you back it up with any documentation?  7-zip has a lot of options for gzip, maybe some of them could be configured to match CLI GZIP.

Comment: [This](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/winrar-winzip-7-zip-magicrar,3436-9.html) is the best test I can Goggle right now.  I made a small gzip comparison with gzip vs 7zip vs zopfli a week ago; I'll have to add more tests & formatting which will add time.

In the mean while, why don't you provide such tests to prove your point please? :)

Comment: @tomByrer Oh, I think you're confused. Maybe I need to re-word my answer.  7-Zip (the **application**) supports multiple compression formats, including GZIP.  I'm not talking about 7z (the **compression format**), which is undoubtedly better than gzip.

Comment: I understand; I've used 7zip to produce gzip files. .7z won't open in browsers :)
However, I always use the Ultra level, 258 (max) word size.  So you can be correct that 7zip to size what servers' gzip will produce.  I am truly interested in knowing that settings.

Do all servers use the same gzip config?

Comment: https://zopfli.googlecode.com/files/Data_compression_using_Zopfli.pdf by Jyrki Alakuijala, Ph.D. and Lode Vandevenne, M.Sc. (Google Inc.) tested `gzip ­9` vs `7­zip ­mm=Deflate ­mx=9`.  7zip was constantly smaller in varying degrees.  If the range of variance was smaller, I would recommend it (I'm a 7-zip fanboi myself).

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer with a quick test.  I tested google.com, and found that 7-zip was 3% smaller.  For most people, this ought to be acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

http://refresh-sf.com/ will give you minification and gzip ratios & sizes.

Answer (score 5):

With node core, you can use the length of the zlib.gzip buffer to determine the gzip size:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const gzip = util.promisify(zlib.gzip);

const getGzipSize = filePath => readFile(filePath)
  .then(gzip)
  .then(x => x.length);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was seeking, to use it with the github script action. Also there are the sync api available:
`const gzipSizeInKb = Math.round((zlib.gzipSync(content).length / 1024) * 100) / 100;`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare uncompressed, gzipped, and brotli'ed file sizes **for the whole folder:** (assuming you want to filter `*.js`):

```
for file in *.js; do printf "$file\t$(cat $file | wc -c)\t$(gzip -kc7 $file | wc -c)\t$(brotli --in $file --out temp.br --force --quality 11 && cat temp.br | wc -c)\n"; done | tee filesizes.log
```

Sample output (tab-separated so you can copy to a spreadsheet):

```
foo.js 39035   10150   8982
bar.js 217000  68978   56337
```

Comment: Removed usage of unnecessary temp file, and saving of output to `filesizes.log`. Added commas to output to improve readability. Bumped gzip compression level to 9 to match the already maxed-out brotli compression level of 11.
```for file in *.js; do printf "$file\t$(cat $file | wc -c | xargs printf "%'d\n")\t$(gzip -9c $file | wc -c | xargs printf "%'d\n")\t$(brotli -cZ $file | wc -c | xargs printf "%'d\n")\n"; done | tee```

Answer (score 0):

You can install `gzip` itself on Windows via [Gow (Gnu On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in VSCode, then I can recommend this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkxml.vscode-filesize

[image]